# Rails 5 + Webpacker + react. Can't find application.js in system test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

My app works in dev and in prod fine, but when I run a simple rails 5 system test I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/packs-test/application-ba6af2abeb41bbe4ad46.js"
```

I updated to the latest rails version and the latest webpacker.
I've reinstalled webpacker with:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react
```

But I still get the error.

My webpacker.yml is out of the box so nothing special. 
I do see the application.js in the public/packs-test folder.

I'm using minitest for testing and really just visiting the sign in page causes the error.

```
visit sign_in_path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ugh, this was caused by a setting in test.rb.

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

I had it changed to false (it should be true like shown above) because of a recommendation by simplecov to overcome some coverage misreporting due to spring.

Answer (score 7):

Try running `RAILS_ENV=test ./bin/rails webpacker:compile` before running your tests.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to help.  File file exists in the public/packs-test directory, but it's just not working.  Weird.